# Pass Date and Time to sql server 2014 returns java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, android, sql-server, datetime, datetime-format

This post is related to my previous post.
Recently i have a project in which i should send an string and two datetime field to SQL Server 2014 and get some fields.(Locaitions)
So i created two DatePicker, that End User can select the date he want.
And instance of a Calender. 
Well,with help of my friends here, i used this till now :

```
            Calendar finalCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int fDay = datePicker2.getDayOfMonth();
            int fMonth = datePicker2.getMonth();
            int fYear = datePicker2.getYear();
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, fYear);
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, fMonth);
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, fDay);
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            finalCalendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
            SimpleDateFormat fSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            setFinalDate(fSimpleDateFormat.format(finalCalendar.getTime()));
```

Well, when i pass it to my SP,it gives me :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "18 12:00:00.000"
```

That 18 is the day i have chosen, and 12 as you see is the time i have set to 0,also Minute,Second and mili second.

And i try below code to see if the time the code returns is true or not :

```
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getFinalDate(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and it shows correct time that i have chosen from DatePicker.
And when i insert this format of time in SQL Server Management Console it works properly.

And i pass this to SQL Server Stored Procedure from android as below.

```
callableStatement.setDate(3, java.sql.Date.valueOf(getFinalDate()));
```

I tried different ways in google.
Different formats of SimpleDateFormat.
I think somewhere i make a mistake.
Any help will appreciate.

And I have a ConnectionHelper Class that works correctly.
I Instance of this.
And call CallableStatement.

```
            CallableStatement callableStatement;
            ConnectionHelper connectionHelper1 = new ConnectionHelper();

            try {
                callableStatement = connectionHelper1.getMyConnection().prepareCall("{call SpSelectTrackVehiclePath(?, ?, ?)}");
                callableStatement.setString(1, IMEArrayAdapter.getItem(listView.getCheckedItemPosition()));//IMEArrayAdapter in below will explain,gives the first field of SP.


                callableStatement.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(startCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
                callableStatement.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(finalCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));

                callableStatement.addBatch();
                callableStatement.executeBatch();

                ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();

                if(resultSet.next()) {
                    do {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bingoo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        spOut.add(resultSet.getDouble("Latitude"));
                        i++;
                    } while (resultSet.next());
                }else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The first Field of this is String that i get from another Table of DB.
Like this(In onCreate Method) :

```
ConnectionHelper connectionHelper = new ConnectionHelper();
    try {
        Statement statement = connectionHelper.getMyConnection().createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Id from Device");
        while(resultSet.next())
        {
            String ime;
            ime = resultSet.getString("Id");
            IMEIs.add(ime); //This is ArrayList<String> Type
            IMEArrayAdapter.getItemViewType(R.id.listView); //get the listView id in XML,
            listView.setAdapter(IMEArrayAdapter); //with this line it set Adapter and all id shows in my ListView
        }
        connectionHelper.closeConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        connectionHelper.closeConnection();
    }
```

And In MSSQL Server Management when i execute this SP with fiels Like this :
IMEI : xxxxxxx
firsDate : 2015-11-18 12:00:00:00
lastDate : 2015-11-24 12:00:00:00
It returns the values.
I execute like this is MSSQL Server Management Studio :

```
USE [xxxxx]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[xxxxxx]
        @DeviceId = N'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        @DateTimeBegin = N'2015-11-18 00:00:00:000',
        @DateTimeEnd = N'2015-11-24 00:00:00:000'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I copy the execute code of SP in MSSQL Server Management Studio.(above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not see what your `getFinalDate()` is returning I guess the String `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`, the correct way on `java.sql.Date.valueOf` should be `yyyy-MM-dd`, do not include the time

but since you have the `Calender` object why not do something like this  (avoid all parsing)

```
callableStatement.setDate(3, new java.sql.Date(finalCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
```

**important** is that your column on database is of type `DATE`

if it is `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` you should use:

```
callableStatement.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(finalCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
```

and yes in this case passing string in valueOf, the string format should be `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

**EDIT:** This has nothing to do with original question but a follow up on CallableStatement.

If the callable statement is a query (return resultset), you need to registrer output and you do not `addBatch` the code would be something like this:

```
callableStatement = connectionHelper1.getMyConnection().prepareCall("{call SpSelectTrackVehiclePath(?, ?, ?,?)}");
callableStatement.setString(1, IMEArrayAdapter.getItem(listView.getCheckedItemPosition()));//IMEArrayAdapter in below will explain,gives the first field of SP.

callableStatement.setTimestamp(2, new java.sql.Timestamp(startCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));
callableStatement.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(finalCalendar.getTimeInMillis()));

callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);

ResultSet resultSet = callableStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thx for your reply.
But i try both way you said.
And put an integer that returns the number of resultSet.
By this way : 

                    if(resultSet.next()) {
                        do {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bingoo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            i++;
                        } while (resultSet.next());

And print the i after while loop, but it returns the default value wich is 0.
in Logcat there is no error with these way you said.( And with yyyy-MM-dd)
The field type in SQL Server is datetime.

Comment: callableStatement.setTimestamp(...) is the correct way for type datetime, if it's not inserted check that you have callableStatement.addBatch();
callableStatement.executeBatch();
connection.commit(); (if its not on autocommit), if you still  have problem edit question inserting your code that is executing the insert/update

Comment: Thx.I Edit it now.
I have worked with this DB before.
I edit it now.

Comment: @alireza azadi. Sorry can't understand comment, "I edit it now", the question?, or now you edit the code so its working?

Comment: The Question Dude. :-D

Comment: @alireza azadi, Your are sure that connectionHelper1.getMyConnection() is autocomit?, if not you need to commit() before you execute query, if its already auto commit, check the call SpSelectTrackVehiclePath(?, ?, ?), why not do directly a insert into....

Comment: I added : 
connectionHelper1.getMyConnection().commit();
But no luck.
Look, The collation of this DB was PERSIAN, and i changed it to Latin1_General_100_CI_AS
Can it be the cause?
Even i select from DB, it does not return the values.
And also i have to use this SP.
Project manager force me.

Comment: after callableStatement.executeBatch();?, if its not working and you have no stacktrace, check the callableStatment (if no stacktrace the code is executing), so it seems that the callableStatment is not working as you expect

Comment: @alireza azadi When i look at your code it seems strange the callablestatment it seems like its an update/insert, you do not register any out parameters?, why do you query it?, maybe its better that you pass the sql of your callablestatment, in question.... or if you are only doing 1 insert, do not use addBatch, but executeUpdate and check the result of this..., hence no query on the callablestatment

Comment: @alireza azadi, I added some to my answer, I don't know what your callablestatment do, but if something like (first I insert, then I do some other stuff , then I query) the code should  something like in answer....

Comment: The first field in DB is varcahr(25), Before two datetime.
As you saw in my code.
Can it be the cause of not working callableStatement?

Comment: I can't see the sql of your callable statment, only what you execute in  Management Studio, if the callable statment returns a resultset you need to  only executeQuery... (if you have no errors, the callable statment is working its only not doing what you expect...)

Comment: @alireza azadi, pass the sql of your callable statment and I will help you out... need to see the order of in parameter and out parameter... (I have a feeling that you have more then 3 parameter, maybe you have the 4 out parameter??, (see the final part of my answer, but I'm guessing order and  number of parameter)

Comment: It retuens some parameters, but not as an output.
Here is what i see in modify of SP.
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpSelectTrackVehiclePath]

   [@]DeviceId varchar(25),
   [@]DateTimeBegin datetime,
   [@]DateTimeEnd datetime

   
-- WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
 BEGIN TRY
  Set TRAN Isolation Level READ COMMITTED
  BEGIN TRAN;
   
   SELECT [IMEI]
      ,[CommandCode]
      ,E.[Event]
      ,[EventCode]
      ,[Latitude]
      ,[Longitude]
      ,[Speed]
      ,[Altitude]
      ,[LocatedDateTime]
      ,[Mileage]
      ,[Heading]
      ,[TemperatureIndexValue]
      ,T.[ModifiedDateTime]

Comment: ,V.[ModelName] AS VehicleModelName
      ,V.[ModelType] AS VehicleModelType
      ,V.[RegisterationNumber] AS VehicleRegistrationNumber
      ,V.[RegistrationNumberSuffix] AS VehicleRegistrationNumberSuffix
      ,C.[B] AS ColorBlue
      ,C.[G] AS ColorGreen
      ,C.[GECode] AS ColorGECode
      ,C.[Hex] AS ColorHex
      ,C.[R] AS ColorRed
      ,C.[Name] AS ColorName
      ,P.[FirstName] + ' ' + P.[LastName] AS DriverName
     FROM [Hyperion].[dbo].[TrackerData] AS T
    INNER JOIN [Hyperion].[dbo].[Vehicle] AS V
    ON T.[IMEI] = V.[DeviceId]
     INNER JOIN  (

Comment: SELECT [DriverId],[VehicleId]
         FROM [Hyperion].[dbo].[Driver'N'Vehicle]
         WHERE [DateOfDischarge] IS NULL
        ) AS DV
        
     ON V.[Id] = DV.[VehicleId]
      INNER JOIN [Hyperion].[dbo].[Person] AS P
      ON P.[Id] = DV.DriverId
       INNER JOIN [Hyperion].[dbo].[EventCode] AS E
       ON E.Code = T.EventCode
        INNER JOIN [Hyperion].[dbo].[Color] AS C
        ON V.ColorId = C.Id

Comment: WHERE [GPSStatus] = 'A' AND 
     [IMEI] = [@]DeviceId AND
     [LocatedDateTime] >= [@]DateTimeBegin AND [LocatedDateTime] <= [@]DateTimeEnd
   ORDER BY LocatedDateTime
    
  COMMIT TRAN
 END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
  RollBack TRAN
  EXECUTE dbo.SpGetErrorInfo
 END CATCH
END

...........................

I had to put @ in [] in all CM, so stack let me to post my CM.

Comment: This looks like a select (no insert nor update) with no out parameters... you need out parameters if you like to read them (select field into field_out)... either change the procedure to included out parameters, or why not create a view, or execute directly the sql in java code (through normal  Statement) passing the parameter in where

Comment: I will try in a day.
I was busy with another thing.
Really Thx Petter, For the time you spent.
I will let you know.
;-)
And give you feedback.

Comment: I forgot about SP, I used a view,But View does not work.
However i have used other Views and Sp from this DB before,So i went to the Table of This.
It has about 28,000,000 row !! (Can it be the cause of fail in select? )
We made a View to use this,But still can not select from this and it returns nothing.But from another Views with the code below it works perfectly.( I mean it returns resultset )

Comment: Here is my Code :         statement=connectionHelper1.getMyConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Latitude from View_4 where IMEI='xxxx'");
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        i++;
}
When i enter this query in SQL Management studio it works in about 3 seconds.
But from android can not return any row.
But when i select from anothers View like View_2 and print the i variable,it shows exactly the number of rows.

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you mean, need to see all relevant java code.., maybe its better that you open a new question?

Comment: Ok,I ask a new question now.
Thx